# Programmatically setting a MailItem's followup flag to complete?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm trying to find out how to set a MailItem's followup flag to completed via VBA in Outlook 2007?

Googling returns a lot of hits for methods that were valid in Outlook 2003 and before (for example, changing the value of the MailItem's FlagStatus property, as is demonstrated in [Outlook 2007 - Email Flag Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650851/outlook-2007-email-flag-status)), however Microsoft overhauled flagging for OL 2007 and the FlagStatus property is no longer available in OL2007 (despite what is implied by the link above).

Does anyone know how to set the currently selected MailItem's follow-up status to completed in OL2007 VBA?

Any advice or working code would be appreciated!

planetthoughtful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
''Case sensitive
If oItem.FlagRequest = "Follow up" Then
    oItem.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
End If
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212007(office.11).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212013(office.11).aspx

Outlook 2010 Help, my highlight

MailItem.`FlagRequest` Property
Returns or sets a String that indicates the requested action for a mail item.
 Read/write.
Version Information
 Version Added:  `Outlook 2007`

Syntax

expression.FlagRequest

Comment: As mentioned above, FlagStatus isn't available as a property of MailItem in OL2007. The links you pasted are for Office 2003. Thanks all the same!

Comment: @planetthoughtful I tested with Outlook 2010. I have added a cut-and-paste from the 2010 help text. I think there may be a misprint in the links.

Comment: Hmmm. This is odd. "FlagRequest" still exists as a property of MailItem in OL2007, but "FlagStatus" doesn't appear to exist. It doesn't come up via code completion (while "FlagRequest" does), and it isn't in the Object Browser for MailItem.

Comment: And there you have it. If you ignore the fact that it doesn't appear to exist, it works... How weird. By the way, it appears you have to call MailItem.Save after changing the FlagStatus for it to take effect.

Comment: I don't know about OL2007 or OL2010, but the documentation for OL2013 and later lists FlagStatus, FlagIcon, etc., as depecated. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx