# How to send follow up email if no response?

Tags: vba, outlook

In the code below I don’t understand how the subroutine checks if the emails coming through are a reply of an email previously sent.

The first subroutine seems to check if the subject line of an incoming email matches this condition: "re: " & strSubject Or InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), strSubject)

After that I am confused. The only way the code works for me is by using categories. It does not work as shown below.

```
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInboxItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

'If receive the reply, clear the flag and remove the reminder
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objSentItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim objVariant As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim dSendTime As String
 
    Set objSentItems = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       For i = 1 To objSentItems.Count
           If objSentItems.Item(i).Class = olMail And **objSentItems.Item(i).categories = "Not Completed"** Then
              Set objVariant = objSentItems.Item(i)
              strSubject = LCase(objVariant.Subject)
              dSendTime = objVariant.SentOn
 
              If LCase(Item.Subject) = "re: " & strSubject Or InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), strSubject) > 0 Then
                 If Item.SentOn > dSendTime Then
                    With objVariant
                         .ClearTaskFlag
                         .ReminderSet = False
                         .Save
                    End With
                 End If
              End If
           End If
       Next i
    End If
End Sub

'Get a prompt asking if to send a notification email
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim nResponse As Integer
    Dim objFollowUpMail As Outlook.MailItem
 
    'You can change the subject as per your real case
    If (Item.Class = olMail) And (LCase(Item.Subject) = "datanumen outlook repair") Then
       strPrompt = "You haven't yet recieved the reply of " & Chr(34) & Item.Subject & Chr(34) & " within your expected time. Do you want to send a follow-up notification email?"
       nResponse = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm to Send a Follow-Up Notification Email")
       If nResponse = vbYes Then
          Set objFollowUpMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
          With objFollowUpMail
               .To = Item.Recipients.Item(1).Address
               .Subject = "Follow Up: " & Chr(34) & Item.Subject & Chr(34)
               .Body = "Please respond to my email " & Chr(34) & Item.Subject & Chr(34) & "as soon as possible"
               .attachments.Add Item
               .Display
          End With
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is unlikely code relying on flags remains functional. As you have discovered you are to apply categories now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650851/set-email-flag-status-in-outlook-2007 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987699/vba-replacement-for-flag-status

Comment: as you can see in the sub routine objInboxItems_ItemAdd i added a category " Not Completed" on my sent emails . it should work with my emails marked as "Not Completed" but it does not clear the flag or the reminder.

Comment: Possible responders might try to recreate the situation, if you update your question to describe how you set the flag and the reminder on the sent item.

Answer (score 0):

The code just needs better commenting. The basic logic is: When a new email comes in, check if it's a reply to any email in the sent box. If so, remove the task and reminder flags from the sent email.

```
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInboxItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

'If receive the reply, clear the flag and remove the reminder
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 'New item received in inbox
    Dim objSentItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim objVariant As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim dSendTime As String
 
    ' get all emails in sent box
    Set objSentItems = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then 'if new inbox item is email 
       For i = 1 To objSentItems.Count   'for each item in sent box
           If objSentItems.Item(i).Class = olMail Then  ' if sent item is email
              Set objVariant = objSentItems.Item(i)  'sent email
              strSubject = LCase(objVariant.Subject)  'sent email subject
              dSendTime = objVariant.SentOn  'sent email send date
 
              'Check subject, if new email is reply to sent email, or new email subject contains sent email subject
              If LCase(Item.Subject) = "re: " & strSubject Or InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), strSubject) > 0 Then
                 If Item.SentOn > dSendTime Then ' if new email has later send date then sent email (else can't be reply)
                    With objVariant  'with sent email
                         .ClearTaskFlag  ' clear flag
                         .ReminderSet = False 'remove reminder
                         .Save
                    End With
                 End If
              End If
           End If
       Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to review and answer my question,  i am tracking email sent with a specific subject : " Action required". i usually send 200 emails with the same subject line, so i think i should try something different like a categories..flag all sent email with  a "follow up" categories. looking for a specific subject does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

The code listed above is badly written and wrong in general. The ItemAdd event is fired when an item is added to the folder, not received. For example, a user may move some items from one folder to another triggering this event. If you want to handle all incoming emails you need to handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.NewMailEx) event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, *MailItem*, *MeetingItem*, or *SharingItem*. The *EntryIDsCollection* string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

```
 For i = 1 To objSentItems.Count   'for each item in sent box
           If objSentItems.Item(i).Class = olMail Then  ' if sent item is email
```

Instead of interating over all items in the folder and finding items that correspond to your conditions I'd recommend using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the situation, given flags are not reliable in my setup.

It may be possible to remove reminders by reinitializing `ReminderTime`.

Code for ThisOutlookSession

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub


Private Sub test_objInboxItems_ItemAdd()
    ' For testing select a reply to the flagged sent item
    objInboxItems_ItemAdd ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
End Sub


Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    ' If reply received,
    '   clear the flag and remove the reminder from the corresponding sent item
    
    ' No attempt to make the logic efficient
    '  - Find / Restrict in the sent items folder
    
    '  In my setup
    '   - TaskDueDate is always 4501-01-01 (no date)
    '   - Reminders on mailitems are not functional
        
    Dim objSentItems As Items
    Dim objVariant As Variant
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strSubject As String
        
    Set objSentItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
    
    If Item.Class = olmail Then
    
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "Item.Subject ...........: " & Item.Subject
        
        For i = 1 To objSentItems.Count
        
            If objSentItems.Item(i).Class = olmail Then
           
                Set objVariant = objSentItems.Item(i)
                strSubject = LCase(objVariant.Subject)
                
                If objVariant.ReminderTime <> "4501-01-01" Then
                 
                    Debug.Print " strSubject ............: " & strSubject
                    Debug.Print " objVariant.SentOn .....: " & objVariant.SentOn
                    Debug.Print " objVariant.ReminderTime: " & objVariant.ReminderTime
                  
                    If LCase(Item.Subject) = "re: " & strSubject Or InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), strSubject) > 0 Then
                
                        'Debug.Print " Item.SentOn .....: " & Item.SentOn
                        'Debug.Print " objVariant.SentOn: " & objVariant.SentOn
                      
                        If Item.SentOn > objVariant.SentOn Then
                   
                            Debug.Print " * strSubject ......: " & strSubject
                            Debug.Print " * Item.SentOn .....: " & Item.SentOn
                            Debug.Print " * objVariant.SentOn: " & objVariant.SentOn
                   
                            If Now > objVariant.ReminderTime Then
                                With objVariant
                                    ' remove flag
                                    .ClearTaskFlag
                                  
                                    ' attempt to remove reminder
                                    .ReminderSet = False
                                  
                                    ' reinitializing ReminderTime may have an impact
                                    .ReminderTime = "4501-01-01"
                                  
                                    .Save
                                  
                                    Debug.Print " ** Flag removed."
                                    Debug.Print " ** Reminder removal attempted."
                                End With
                            End If
                        
                        End If
                        
                    Else
                        Debug.Print " *** subject does not match"

                    End If
                    
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "done"
    
End Sub


Private Sub test_ToggleMarkAsTaskFlagAndSetReminder()
    ' for testing
    '  select a mailitem in the sent items folder to add a flag and a reminder
    ToggleMarkAsTaskFlagAndSetReminder ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
End Sub


Private Sub ToggleMarkAsTaskFlagAndSetReminder(ByVal objItem As Object)

    '  In my setup
    '   - TaskDueDate is always 4501-01-01 (no date)
    '   - Reminders on mailitems are not functional
        
    If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
    
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "objItem.Subject .............: " & objItem.Subject
        Debug.Print " objItem.TaskDueDate  Current: " & objItem.TaskDueDate
        Debug.Print " objItem.ReminderTime Current: " & objItem.ReminderTime
        
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmarkinterval
        If objItem.IsMarkedAsTask = False Then
            
            objItem.MarkAsTask (olMarkThisWeek)
            Debug.Print " * Marked as task"
            
            ' In my setup - TaskDueDate is always 4501-01-01
            Debug.Print " objItem.TaskDueDate  Updated?: " & objItem.TaskDueDate
            Debug.Print " objItem.ReminderTime Updated?: " & objItem.ReminderTime
            
            ' In my setup - Reminders on mailitems are not functional
            Debug.Print " objItem.ReminderSet Current: " & objItem.ReminderSet
            objItem.ReminderSet = True
            Debug.Print " objItem.ReminderSet Updated: " & objItem.ReminderSet
            
            objItem.ReminderTime = DateAdd("d", -7, Now) ' testing
            Debug.Print " objItem.ReminderTime Updated: " & objItem.ReminderTime
            
        Else 'Reinitialize item
        
            objItem.ClearTaskFlag
            Debug.Print " * Task cleared"
            
            ' TaskDueDate not functional in my setup, remains 4501-01-01
            Debug.Print " objItem.TaskDueDate  Updated?: " & objItem.TaskDueDate
            
            objItem.ReminderSet = False
            Debug.Print " objItem.ReminderSet = False"
            objItem.ReminderTime = "4501-01-01"
            Debug.Print " objItem.ReminderTime Updated: " & objItem.ReminderTime
            
        End If
        
        'objItem.Display
        objItem.Save
        
    Else
    
        Debug.Print "not a mailitem"
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nilton, i tried your code, i had 53 reminders (pop ups) and they are all gone, i only have some items in my "to do list" now... can you elaborate more on the following condition : objVariant.ReminderTime <> "4501-01-01" . also i am not getting pop ups reminders for upcoming calendar event anymore..not sure if this is linked to the script

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmarkinterval "... the empty date value (#1/1/4501#)"

Comment: The code should have impacted mailitems in the sent items folder. It is not apparent how other than those were impacted. For the future, put in a breakpoint to see when code is triggered. Step through to see which reminders are being updated.